# how to use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP in android?

Tags: android, contacts

I wordering how to use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP in android ?

Below is my code which shows IllegalStateException.

```
    Cursor allContacts = this.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    StringBuilder sbCurrentVersion = new StringBuilder();
    allContacts.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < allContacts.getCount(); i++) {
        String id = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String col = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));
        sbCurrentVersion.append("  "+id+":"+name+" : "+col);
        allContacts.moveToNext();
    }

         It shows following IllegalStateException
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                                                                                    at com.example.dj.contentobserverdemo.ContentObserverService.sGetCurrentContatcsVersions(ContentObserverService.java:111)
                                                                                    at com.example.dj.contentobserverdemo.ContentObserverService.access$000(ContentObserverService.java:23)
                                                                                    at com.example.dj.contentobserverdemo.ContentObserverService$MyContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserverService.java:83)
                                                                                    at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:130)
                                                                                    at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:216)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: post the stacktrace then

Comment: instead of `getColumnIndex` use `getColumnIndexOrThrow` and you will know what is wrong

Comment: it shows "column 'contact_last_updated_timestamp' does not exist." .. Then how can i get last updated time ??. documentation says this is the way to get updated timestamp which is introduced in API 18

Comment: Did you added read permission for contacts

Comment: you are passing wrong `Uri` to `query()` method

Comment: yes permission is granted. what do you mean by wrong URI ?@ pskink. if it is wrong then post right one please

Comment: try googling then

Comment: hey dont get me wrong. i just want to know right one.

Comment: so you have to do *anything* on your own, i gave you the answer for your `IllegalStateException`, i gave you a suggestion that your `Uri` is wrong, your homework is to find out the right one

Comment: brother my question is how to use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: then find what classes implement the interface where `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer why It shows IllegalStateException. Use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI instead ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI for fetching all contacts

```
Cursor allContacts = this.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

StringBuilder sbCurrentVersion = new StringBuilder();
allContacts.moveToFirst();

for (int i = 0; i < allContacts.getCount(); i++) {
    String id = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String col = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));
    sbCurrentVersion.append("  "+id+":"+name+" : "+col);
    allContacts.moveToNext();
}
```